# how to pass "=" as part of argument to .cmd or .bat file from bit-bash for windows

Tags: batch-file, cmd, git-bash

in git-bash shell that I have open in windows10, this test

```
./test.cmd 123=456
```

returns
`123`

Contents of test.cmd are :

```
echo %1
```

I've tried `./test.cmd 123\=456`   and `123^456` and doesn't work.

If I run `./test.cmd 123=456` from a cmd shell, it works fine and outputs `123=456`.
I can escape other special characters, just not `=`

```
$ ./test.bat "123^^^&456"

C:\Users\551527>echo 123&456
123&456

551527@S29C0N4 MINGW64 ~
$ ./test.bat "123^^^=456"

C:\Users\551527>echo 123

123
```

What's so different about `=`  ?

Comment: I would say it has to do with how Windows interprets batch scripts. This is not Git Bash's doing, but cmd's doing I'm pretty sure. I just ran the same test in `cmd` and get the same results.

Comment: Hum, editing your question, I just noticed you say you get different results in `cmd`, so I tested again, and I really do get `123` when I run `test.cmd 123=456` in cmd. I don't understand why you see different results.

Comment: Furthermore, in `cmd`, `./test.cmd 123=456` gives me the error `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`. I have to run `.\test.cmd 123=456` to get the output `123`, so I have to ask if you're sure that test was really run in `cmd`, even though that might seem like a dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

**First problem: the equal sign is a delimiter in cmd.exe**

If you start a batch file with a delimiter character this simply splits arguments.

```
myBatch.bat three;argu=ments

-- %1 = three
-- %2 = argu
-- %3 = ments
-- %* = three;argu=ments
```

To avoid the splitting you have to use quotes (carets doesn't work here).

```
myBatch.bat "three;argu=ments"

--  %1 = "three;argu=ments"
-- %~1 = three;argu=ments
```

**Second problem: git-bash works different with arguments**

bash has different rules for arguments, it decides what is a single argument **and removes surrounding quotes**

Using

./myBatch.bat "three;argu=ments"

is parsed by bash, a single argument is detected and then cmd.exe is called with this single argument like:

```
cmd /c myBatch.cmd three;argu=ments
```

At this point, it's obvious that you can't build a complex command line, that works for cmd.exe and also from bash.

It's possible to build solutions for concrete problems, but it's always a pain.